# Bullet color in Xaringan presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan, remarkjs

Is it possible to change the bullet colors in Xaringan presentation? The text should have a different color.

I have not find any option in xaringanthemer package neither going through the css file. I could not find any information  remark.js documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the bullet point colour by adding a custom CSS to the YAML header of your Xaringan presentation.

Following is a fully reproducible minimal example.

### Markdown file

````
title: "Example"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: 
        - default
        - default-fonts
        - custom.css
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

## Change bullet point colour

* An item
* Another item
````

### Custom `custom.css`

We have taken the relevant CSS code to theme the bullet points from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bullet_color.asp).

```css
ul {
  list-style: none; /* Remove default bullets */
}

ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";  /* Add content: \2022 is the CSS Code/unicode for a bullet */
  color: red; /* Change the color */
  font-weight: bold; /* If you want it to be bold */
  display: inline-block; /* Needed to add space between the bullet and the text */
  width: 1em; /* Also needed for space (tweak if needed) */
  margin-left: -1em; /* Also needed for space (tweak if needed) */
}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`xaringan` output is html so you can change any parts by css (e.g. using [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bullet_color.asp) to change bullet color to a red dot. Taking this as a template, you can add this chunk soon after the YAML of the Rmd to change it to a red bullet:

````
```{css, echo=F}
ul {
  list-style: none; /* Remove default bullets */
}

ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";  /* Add content: \2022 is the CSS Code/unicode for a bullet */
  color: red; /* Change the color */
  font-weight: bold; /* If you want it to be bold */
  display: inline-block; /* Needed to add space between the bullet and the text */ 
  width: 1em; /* Also needed for space (tweak if needed) */
  margin-left: -1em; /* Also needed for space (tweak if needed) */
}
```
````

### Separate style from content

Or more preferably (since it separates out the style component from slide content), create a css file, say `style.css` which contains:

```
ul {
  list-style: none; /* Remove default bullets */
}

ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";  /* Add content: \2022 is the CSS Code/unicode for a bullet */
  color: red; /* Change the color */
  font-weight: bold; /* If you want it to be bold */
  display: inline-block; /* Needed to add space between the bullet and the text */ 
  width: 1em; /* Also needed for space (tweak if needed) */
  margin-left: -1em; /* Also needed for space (tweak if needed) */
}
```

then add in the YAML, making sure that style.css is in the same path as your Rmd,

```
css: [xaringan-themer.css, style.css]
```

### Tweaking the bullet shape

You can change the shape the bullet using a different unicode supplied in `content` (e.g. use `\2023` for a triangle bullet - see other common types [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(typography)#In_Unicode)).

### Changing the bullet color

You just need to replace `red` with the color of your choice. You can replace it with the hex color code instead too.

Comment: Isn't this in essence the same as the solution I posted earlier?

Comment: Hello Maurits. In my account Emi’s answer is considered the oldest. You solution is also correct.

Comment: Both solutions were able to differentiate the color of the bullets from the color of the text. However, when rendering in moon_reader the presentation template (from Yihui Xie) the bullets get vertically in the wrong position. Check slide 5 (first 'red' bullet is ok' but when going further things get mixed.

Comment: @LeonardoRibeiro *" In my account Emi’s answer is considered the oldest."* That is incorrect and can be easily checked if you take a look at the timestamp. Emi's answer is just a slight variation of my earlier post (even with an identical CSS).

Comment: @LeonardoRibeiro PS. You can see the actual timestamp if you hover the mouse over the "answered xx hours ago" message for a few seconds.

Comment: You are right! Your answer was 4 minutes earlier :-) Anyway, I am having trouble since the proposed solutions are not working (when knitting the bullets do not align with the text.

Comment: @LeonardoRibeiro If it's not coming out correctly vertically, try adding `margin-top: 0.5em;` (tweak number as necessary). It does come out correctly on mine but it might be due to font differences etc. 

As for the solution, I didn't see @MauritsEvers solution. There were no answer when I was answering and I suspect that as I was writing the solution, @MauritsEvers was writing theirs.

Comment: @Emi. Both you and Maurits have been of great help. You are probably right about your guess. From what I recall your answer showed in my screen before (probably my mistake anyway). As for your hint, I have tried but it did not work and I figured out why. I was basically using a space between bullets. This works fine in the default xaringan themes. When using the proposed solution the bullets get messed up. This works:
`- One item <br/> - Another item`
This doesn't work: 
`- One item <br/> <br/> - Another item`

Comment: @LeonardoRibeiro Great that you found a working solution!