# custom.css disappears when using Xaringan

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I'm new in this fabulous Xaringan's world, so sorry if my question is too simple. I've found this question about changing the [bullet point colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56338948/bullet-color-in-xaringan-presentation) and I tried to replicate it.

I've created the `custom.css` file and stored it in remark-css folder but, every time I run the `.rmd`, the `custom.css` file disappears and I don't get the expected results, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you running the .rmd file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to replicate as follows. New to R so had to do some setup.

- Install R and R tools
- Install R Studio
- Install xaringan package

In R Studio (testing.rmd)

- File > New File > R Markdown > From Template > Ninja Presentation
- Delete all the slides and created my own slide

testing.rmd

```
---
title: "Hello World"
subtitle: "testing"
author: "Hassan Voyeau"
institute: "TTR"
date: "19/9/2019 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["default", "custom.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

HELLO WORLD

* Item 1
* Item 2
```

custom.css (in the same folder as testing.rmd)

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li::before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    margin-left: -1em;
}
```

And the results

[image: testing]

Comment: I had R tools, R Studion and Xaringan already installed. But following your suggestions I removed everything before running the `.rmd` and now it works! I guess, my problem was also I put the `custom.css` file in the wrong directory. I placed it with `default` and `default-fonts` instead of the `.rmd` file. Thanks for your help!